# jQuery trying to add br tag for every span that is ""

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am developing and typing test game using jQuery and Laravel. The test is stored from Laravel and displayed on another page.

Now, when I save `enter` in db it saves it and when I display it on the page, I somehow managed to read it as `enter`

**The issue**: when the document is ready, I split each test character to a `span` for some extra work. And it doesn't read the break line. What can I do to get those spans who are empty?

I have been catching those span like this `$(span[counter]).text() == "\n"` and then I add the `br` tag when user is typing, but what I want is when the page loads it should have `br` tag after that `span` which is "\n". Please, guide me here

My code:

```js
var inputString = "";
var inputStringEnter = "";
var testString = $('.val').text();

var pass = "<span>" + $('.val').text().split("").join("</span><span style='white-space: pre' class='empty'>") + "</span>";
$('.val').html(pass);
var testSpans = document.querySelectorAll(".val span");

function matchLetter(e) {
  if (continueTyping == true) {
    $('.hidden-input').focus();
    isIgnored = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
      if (counter > 0) {
        inputString = inputString.substr(0, inputString.length - 1);
        $(testSpans[counter - 1]).removeClass("spanClass redClass");
        $(testSpans[counter - 1]).addClass("highlight-class");
        $(testSpans[counter]).removeClass("highlight-class");
        $("g[data-key='13']").removeClass("is-active");
        $("div[data-key='13']").removeClass("highlight-class");
        $("div[data-key=" + testString[counter].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) + "]").removeClass("highlight-class");
        if ($(testSpans[counter - 1]).text() != "\n") {
          $("div[data-key=" + testString[counter - 1].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) + "]").addClass("highlight-class");
        } else {
          $("div[data-key='13']").addClass("highlight-class");
        }
        $("g[data-key=" + testString[counter].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) + "]").removeClass("is-active");
        if ($(testSpans[counter - 1]).text() != "\n") {
          $("g[data-key=" + testString[counter - 1].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) + "]").addClass("is-active");
        } else {
          $("g[data-key='13']").addClass("is-active");
        }
        counter--;
      }
    } else {
      if (e.key.length == 1 || e.key == 'Enter') {
        inputString += e.key.substr(0, 1);
        if ($(testSpans[counter]).text() != "\n") {
          if (testString[counter] == inputString[counter]) {
            $(testSpans[counter]).addClass("spanClass");
          } else {
            $(testSpans[counter]).addClass("redClass");
          }
        } else {
          if ($(testSpans[counter]).text() == "\n" && e.key == 'Enter') {
            // console.log('correct')
            $(testSpans[counter]).addClass("spanClass");
          } else {
            $(testSpans[counter]).addClass("redClass");
          }
        }

        $(testSpans[counter + 1]).addClass("highlight-class");
        $(testSpans[counter]).removeClass("highlight-class");

        if ($(".hidden-input").val().length != $(".val").text().length) {
          if ($(testSpans[counter]).text() != "\n") {
            $("div[data-key=" + testString[counter].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) + "]").removeClass("highlight-class");

          } else {
            $("div[data-key='13']").removeClass("highlight-class")
          }
          if ($(testSpans[counter + 1]).text() != "\n") {
            $("div[data-key=" + testString[counter + 1].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) + "]").addClass("highlight-class");
          } else {
            $("div[data-key='13']").addClass("highlight-class")
          }
          if (($(testSpans[counter]).text() != "\n")) {
            $("g[data-key=" + testString[counter].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) + "]").removeClass("is-active");

          } else {
            $("g[data-key='13']").removeClass("is-active");
          }
          if (($(testSpans[counter + 1]).text() != "\n")) {
            console.log('hello')
            $("g[data-key=" + testString[counter + 1].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) + "]").addClass("is-active");
          } else {
            $("g[data-key='13']").addClass("is-active")
          }

        }
        counter++;
      }
    }
    $(".hidden-inputs").val($(".spanClass").length)
  } else {
    $('input').focusout();
    console.log('ignored')
  }
}
});
```

HTML

```html
<div class="screenBasic-word">
  <div class="letter letter--basic screenBasic val">{!! (e($test->paragraph))!!}</div>
  <input type="hidden" class="wps form-control" name="wps">
  <input type="hidden" class="id form-control" value="{{ $test->id }}" name="id">
</div>
```

Comment: add your sample html

Comment: var inputString = "";
        var inputStringEnter = "";
        var testString = $('.val').text();
        var pass = "<span>" + $('.val').text().split("").join("</span><span style='white-space: pre' class='empty'>") + "</span>";

        $('.val').html(pass);
    This code is before my variable var testSpans

Comment: <div class="screenBasic-word">
                                                <div class="letter letter--basic screenBasic val">{!! (e($test->paragraph))!!}</div>

                                                <input type="hidden" class="wps form-control"  name="wps">
                                                <input type="hidden" class="id form-control" value="{{ $test->id }}"  name="id">
                                            </div>      here it is

Comment: This val class div's character is joined in span for each character a different span in side of div with the class of val

Comment: Please edit and post your HTML(other information)  with question not in comment section.

Comment: Not being a native speaker is not a problem, but you should add some punctuations or at least some new lines to your text, instead of writing one single block of text. That helps to read and understand the question, and increases the probability that it is answered.

Comment: Ok i will post it there

Comment: I am sorry i am not getting the edit option probably i have because i have edited it twice i am sorry for this but myabe can any of u help me like this

Comment: @adeelshahid you have used the edit option correctly it was my fault, I had overwritten your changes, because I did get a notification that the post was also edited by you.